# Change TextView text color programmatically

Tags: gridview

I have a gridview inside which I am binding another layout which contains imageview and textview control. Now I want to change textview's text color programmatically based on background set.

I had done it by this way:

((TextView)gridView.findViewById(R.id.textView1))).setColor(Color.BLACK);

But this generates NullPointer Exception

Answer (score 1):

**Try the following code:**

```
TextView mTextView = (TextView) findById(R.id.textView)    
mTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#bdbdbd"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Either your gridView is null, or your gridView doesn't contain the TextView with the ID textView1.  Pretty hard to tell, unless you post code.